# Replacing multiple chars in string with another character in Python

Tags: python, string, replace, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings I want to check if each string contains certain characters, if it does then replace the characters with another character.

I have something like below:

```py
invalid_chars = [' ', ',', ';', '{', '}', '(', ')', '\\n', '\\t', '=']
word = 'Ad{min > HR'
for c in list(word):
  if c in invalid_chars:
    word = word.replace(c, '_')
print (word) 

>>> Admin_>_HR
```

I am trying to convert this into a function using list comprehension but I am strange characters...

```py
def replace_chars(word, checklist, char_replace = '_'):
  return ''.join([word.replace(ch, char_replace) for ch in list(word) if ch in checklist])

print(replace_chars(word, invalid_chars))
>>> Ad_min > HRAd{min_>_HRAd{min_>_HR
```

Comment: The `'\\n'` and `'\\t'` are not single characters though. Perhaps you meant `'\n'` and `'\t'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this general pattern:

```
''.join([ch if ch not in invalid_chars else '_' for ch in word])
```

For the complete function:

```
def replace_chars(word, checklist, char_replace = '_'):
  return ''.join([ch if ch not in checklist else char_replace for ch in word])
```

Note: no need to wrap string `word` in a `list()`, it's already iterable.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a good use for [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate). You can turn your `invalid_chars` into a translation table with [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and apply wherever you need it:

```
invalid_chars = [' ', ',', ';', '{', '}', '(', ')', '\n', '\t', '=']
invalid_table = str.maketrans({k:'_' for k in invalid_chars})

word = 'Ad{min > HR'

word.translate(invalid_table)
```

**Result:**

```
'Ad_min_>_HR'
```

This will be especially nice if you need to apply this translation to several strings and more efficient since you don't need to loop through the entire `invalid_chars` array for every letter, every time which you will if you us `if x in invalid_chars` inside a loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is easier with regex. You can search for a whole group of characters with a single substitution call. It should perform better too.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(f"[{re.escape(''.join(invalid_chars))}]", "_", word)
'Ad_min_>_HR'
```

The code in the f-string builds a regex pattern that looks like this

```
>>> pattern = f"[{re.escape(''.join(invalid_chars))}]"
>>> print(repr(pattern))
'[\\ ,;\\{\\}\\(\\)\\\n\\\t=]'
>>> print(pattern)
[\ ,;\{\}\(\)\
\   =]
```

That is, a regex character set containing each of your invalid chars. (The backslash escaping ensures that none of them are interpreted as a regex control character, regardless of which characters you put in `invalid_chars`.) If you had specified them as a string in the first place, the `''.join()` would not be required.

You can also compile the pattern (using `re.compile()`) if you need to re-use it on multiple words.